# How can we parse DataFrame.describe()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

How can we parse the output from `DataFrame.describe()`? When we print the result of `DataFrame.describe()` as shown in examples, it is in string format, which is why it is difficult to parse it.

I understand that the `print` function might be converting the output into a displayable and readable form. However, it is not easily parseable. How can we achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to parse output as a string?

Comment: Could you put an example of what you mean? I work with it quite often and use the result from df.describe() as a normal dataframe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

Comment: @DJK My question is not about how to parse a DataFrame. My question was how to parse output of describe() of a DataFrame. Hence, both are different.

Comment: @TempO'rary, not really, if the output is a dataframe, then the crux of the question is how do I parse a dataframe. It would be like saying a question phrased as  "how do I create a dataframe and parse" it is not a duplicate of the link I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the output of `describe()` is a dataframe so you can do:

```
df = x.describe()
```

`df` is a standard DataFrame

Comment: So now when I did `df1["numeric"]["mean"]` I get the values. Thanks

Comment: I've suggested an edit for more clarification for someone like a beginner

Comment: exactly. I'd like to add also that it's tempting to do df1["numeric"].mean to access the serie... but mean is a pre-defined function so it doesn't work. df1["numeric"]["mean"] like you did is the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

`print` always prints in string format.

But if you check `type(df.describe())` then you'll see that it is a dataframe. 
So you can treat it like one. :)

Comment: That is a valuable input. Unfortunately I wasn't aware of this. Thank you.